# I can not understand this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a traffic light simulation using JQuery but I am struggling to understand the code I am using. Can anyone explain the function or, maybe, suggest another way to achieve the same result?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="trafficlight">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="red light" id="redlight"></div>
    <div class="orange light" id="orangelight"></div>
    <div class="green light" id="greenlight"></div>
  </div>            
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
  //lights
  function redorange() {
    $('#orangelight').css('opacity', 1)
  };

  function green() {
    $('#redlight').css('opacity', 0.4)
    $('#orangelight').css('opacity', 0.4)
    $('#greenlight').css('opacity', 1)
    clearInterval(first);
  };

  function orange() {
    $('#orangelight').css('opacity', 1)
    $('#greenlight').css('opacity', 0.4)
    clearInterval(second);
  };

  function red() {
    $('#redlight').css('opacity', 1)
    $('#orangelight').css('opacity', 0.4)
    clearInterval(third);
  }; 

  //var first = setInterval(redorange, 4000);

  var second = setInterval(green, 5000);

  var third = setInterval(orange, 8000);

  var fourth = setInterval(red, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: You're only calling two functions, and it's not hard to find their documentation. http://api.jquery.com/css & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: I have no idea of how this code works if your variable "first" is commented and you are using it in green() function...

Comment: @phuzi I've rolled this back because there is clearly some code missing, namely the CSS, so being a snippet isn't helpful.

Comment: @AndrewBone Fair enough, it was broken anyway ;)

Answer (score 2):

The opacity property in CSS specifies how transparent an element is. Basic use: div { opacity: 0.5; } Opacity has a default initial value of 1 (100% opaque). Opacity is not inherited, but because the parent has opacity that applies to everything within it.

Read more about it [here](https://appendto.com/2016/04/5-examples-to-help-you-understand-how-css-opacity-works/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#orangelight').css('opacity', 1)
```

changes opacity `<div class="orange light" id="orangelight"></div>` to 1

---

```
clearInterval(first);
```

stops the time form the interval 'first' (`var first = setInterval(redorange, 4000)`)

---

```
var fourth = setInterval(red, 10000);
```

set an interval to the variable 'fourth' wich calls the function 'orange()' after 10000 ms.

---

Note that `clearInterval(first);` will cause an error and your code will not work because `var first = ...` is commented out, so 'first' is undefined.

> if you want to learn more about jQuery you shold take a look at the
>   docs: https://api.jquery.com/
>
> or take a look at https://www.codecademy.com/ to lean more about JS.

Comment: i want this function to be work for example 10 seconds green, 2 seconds yellow and 5 seconds red by it not works whre should i change them?

Comment: as i mentioned the intervals are set with miliseconds, for 5 seconds you have to set the interval to 5000.

Comment: take a look at [this documentation for setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: you really should start with [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) to learn the basics of programming with JavaScript, instead of trying to build your stuff by copy-pase.